# XCode Debug - Can I bypass stepping through disassembly code

Tags: xcode, debugging, ios

When debugging a project, after setting a breakpoint in XCode I'll start stepping through my code and then I will encounter disassembled code from what I assume are calls to various frameworks that don't have source code available.  (Is this a correct assumption?)  Is there a way (perhaps via a project setting that I haven't found yet) to suppress the display of this assembly code and not have to step though it but just step though the source code that I have implemented?

I see I can click on the the "continue program execution" icon but I am not positive that this is the best technique to accomplish this.  At this stage of my development experience, stepping though the source to better understand code execution and being able to examine data values is very valuable, but stepping though assembly code ... not so much.

I'm using XCode 4 GM but I also encountered this in XCode 3.x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try clicking the "step out" button when you are in code you don't have access to.

Comment: So just so I am clear, "stepping out" will not bypass the execution of the code, just bypass the display of it?

Comment: Yes, in the debugger, if you are stepping over, into or out of code, it will execute the code.

Comment: Found the following in the XCode 4 Transition Guide, in the section on Debugging and Analyzing: "Step out of a jumped-to routine; that is, complete the current routine and step to the next routine or
back to the calling routine."  That answers my question from my comment.  Thanks for the lead to answering my question.

Comment: You sovled this issue? You now never see assembly/disassembly? I still do, despite stepping over (Show Disassembly When Debugging is disabled).