# How do I skip ASM code in Xcode7 Debugger?

Tags: xcode, debugging

Is it possible to step through a Swift & Objective-C program in Xcode 7 without having to waste time endlessly stepping through compiled asm code? For every step I take, I end up spending another minute going through 20+ lines of generated assembly commands, and it doesn't help in the slightest that I just inherited this project a few days ago. I find it hard to believe you HAVE to look at unintelligible code when you want to debug something in a large application.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Edit: Apparently there isn't any way of doing this as of now. After a bit of further browsing typical of newbs ( :) ), I've found two other answered questions confirming this.

[xcode debugging - quickly step over assembly code back to my custom code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438031/xcode-debugging-quickly-step-over-assembly-code-back-to-my-custom-code?rq=1)

[XCode Debug - Can I bypass stepping through disassembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146676/xcode-debug-can-i-bypass-stepping-through-disassembly-code?rq=1)

Comment: What are you doing that takes you into the assembler code? Simply avoid clicking on the "Step Into" button unless you have the source code for the method you are about to step into.

Comment: I don't use "step into", obviously. The problem is even when i use the "step over" button, it still sometimes throws me into the assembly code. Im asking for a way to only skim through my own custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "Step Out" (F8) to pop out of the current routine (which you see in assembler). You have good chances to quickly return to source-mapped area this way (but not always!).

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Is there no other way of making sure I avoid going to the assembler every other step? I guess I won't die if it's not possible, but it is hella annoying that I have to break my mental flow when the only thing I want to check is the control flow of the program.

Comment: If you do recognise when it's safe to "Step Into" and when you actually want "Step Over" and nevertheless accidentally you get into assembly code, I have no more advices. That's probably a bug or non obvious feature of the debugger.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say this. Apple, step up your game!

Comment: So in a way, Apple is making developers waste time pressing F8 trying to get out of something they don't need to look at  or care.  VisualStudio is a much better IDE tool but that's out of context.